# Error 0xc002f210

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have just started learning SQL Server, I am trying to use Import Export wizard to import data from excel file to one of the table in the database. But I am getting an error `0xc002f210`.

I understood only that it is taking length of excel file cell as 255 but the SQL Server table length is different. I am unable to understand why it is happening.

**Validating (Error)**

> Warning 0x802092a7: Data Flow Task 1: Truncation may occur due to inserting data from data flow column "Name" with a length of 255 to database column "Name" with a length of 50.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Warning 0x802092a7: Data Flow Task 1: Truncation may occur due to inserting data from data flow column "GroupName" with a length of 255 to database column "GroupName" with a length of 50.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc002f210: Preparation SQL Task 1: Executing the query "TRUNCATE TABLE [HumanResources].[Department]
>   " failed with the following error: "Cannot truncate table 'HumanResources.Department' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Answer (score 0):

So the error you are receiving is different from the warnings that you are getting. The warnings are simply informing you that you are taking a larger column and putting it into a smaller column, so there is the possibility of data truncation.

The error will give you some insight into the purpose of using a Foreign Key Constraint.  The technet article will give you an in depth understanding of it if you read through it. 
[TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

But essentially, referential integrity by way of foreign key constraints make it so that the "link" between data cannot be broken on the Primary Key side (table "Department").  In order to delete data from the Primary Key table, you must first either remove the foreign key, or delete the data first from the Foreign Key table.

You should re-evaluate two things:

1) Whether you actually should be truncating the Primary key table

2) Which table has a foreign key linked to the Department table's primary key.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got the cause of error, but I don't understand why it is throwing warning when I try to load data from excel file, It is taking the column length as 255 from excel,It should not be like this.